# Что можно добавить в калькулятор Python

Tags: python

Что можно добавить в калькулятор? Очень интересно а то фантазия закончилась.

```
print("Выберите Что Хотите Сделать:")
print("1 Сложение")
print("2 Вычитание")
print("3 Умножение")
print("4 Деление")
user = input("")
if user == "1":
    number_one = float(input("Первое Число: "))
    number_two = float(input("Второе Число:"))
    print(number_one + number_two)
if user == "2":
    number_one = float(input("Первое Число: "))
    number_two = float(input("Второе Число:"))
    print(number_one - number_two)
if user == "3":
    number_one = float(input("Первое Число: "))
    number_two = float(input("Второе Число:"))
    print(number_one * number_two)
if user == "4":
    number_one = float(input("Первое Число: "))
    number_two = float(input("Второе Число:"))
    print(number_one / number_two)
```

Comment: Как минимум в цикл это всё завернуть.

Comment: Пользовательский интерфейс

Answer (score 1):

посмотри на обычный бухгалтерский калькулятор.
- запомнить в память
- извлечь из памяти
- операция с памятью (+-)
- проценты
...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй посмотреть на [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org). Там можно делать такое:

```
>>> solve(x**2 - 2, x)
[-√2, √2]
```